Не работает xscroll в tkinter, python
Я использую python, tkinter. У меня есть таблица и две scroll полоски к ней, горизонтальная и вертикальная. вертикальная работает исправно, горизонтальная нет, единственное отличие это то что горизонтальная находиться на другом frame, в отличии от самой таблицы.
self.coloms=("res")
self.table_res=ttk.Treeview(self.frame_main, columns=self.coloms,show="headings")
self.table_res.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,expand=True)

self.table_res.heading("res",text="Результаты")
self.table_res.column("res",stretch=NO,width=470)
    
self.scroll=ttk.Scrollbar(self.frame_main, orient=tk.VERTICAL,command=self.table_res.yview)
self.scroll.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    
self.scroll_x=ttk.Scrollbar(self.frame_but, orient='horizontal',command=self.table_res.xview)
self.scroll_x.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
    
self.table_res.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set,xscrollcommand=self.scroll_x.set)

Обязательно ли скроллам находиться на одном фрейме с таблицей? если да, можно как то урегулировать размер таблицы (по вертикали, чтобы вместить горизонтальный скролл)

Сейчас на вашем коде нельзя ничего проверить, он вырезан из класса. Добавьте минимальный воспроизводимый пример, демонстрирующий проблему. Необязательно в одном фрейме, главное чтобы привязано было в обе стороны (command у полосы прокрутки и xscrollcommand/yscrollcommand у таблицы). Почему горизонтальная прокрутка "не работает" - ну куча причин может быть, начиная с того, что если контент помещается (по горизонтали или по вертикали) - то соответствующая полоса прокрутки становится неактивной.
